# How to show DevExpress PivotGrid fit to screen

Tags: asp.net, .net, devexpress

I am unable to show pivotgrid size,fit to screen.
I have tried `BestFit();`
and `BestFitColumnArea();`
But that doesn't work.
I am able to show GridView by setting the property `OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth=True;`

Answer (score 0):

- Set the ASPxPivotGrid.Width to 100%;
- Use recommendations from the [ASPxPivotGrid - How to switch a control to full screen mode](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q281778) thread.